# What is ID in leaflet code for L.tileLayer

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, tile-layer, token

I'm working with this famous code:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', 
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'CAN'T FIND IT',
    accessToken: 'FOUND IT'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

I can't find the ID of my mapbox but when i change it to mapbox.streets, the map shows up.
Mapbox gives me a style URL, what should i do with it?

Answer (score 1):

I found how to get the ID for my map
Go to TILESITS

[image]

Then choose your map

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Mapbox Studio go to Styles and choose "Share, develop & use"

[image]

Then under "Develop with this style" choose "Leaflet".

[image]

You can then just copy paste that URL directly:

```
L.tileLayer('LEAFLET URL FROM MAPBOX', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i guess this is a style URL anyway it worked